# Select from two tables using "NOT IN" in LINQ in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

i have the following SQL, how can i implement that in LINQ, i am using Entity framework in my MVC project.

```
  SELECT 
  * FROM Catalog.ServiceItem 
  WHERE SKU NOT IN (SELECT ServiceItemSKU FROM Catalog.TaggedServiceItems)
```

Any Ideas ?

**EDIT:
ANSWER:**

```
var untaggedItems = from item in serviceItems where !taggedServiceItems.Contains(item.SKU) select item;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this with `Contains`:

```
var result = from item in ServiceItem
    where !TaggedServiceItems.Contains(item.SKU)
    select item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var Catalog_ServiceItem = ds.Tables["Catalog.ServiceItem"].AsEnumerable();
var Catalog_TaggedServiceItems = ds.Tables["Catalog.TaggedServiceItems"].AsEnumerable();
var _except = from c in Catalog_ServiceItem 
                   join b in Catalog_TaggedServiceItems 
                     on c.Field<string>("ServiceItemSKU ") equals b.Field<string>("ServiceItemSKU ") into j
                   from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where x == null
                   select c;
```

**EDIT**

You can do this

```
var _except = Catalog_ServiceItem.Except(Catalog_TaggedServiceItems);
```

Comment: I like using the EXCEPT, its only one line, leaves the code neat and clean . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

use lambda.

```
dim query=Catalog.ServiceItem.where(function(q) not q.Contains(q.SKU))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var untaggedItems = 
  from i in Catalog.ServiceItem
  let taggedItems = (
    from ti = Catalog.TaggedServiceItems
    select ti.ServiceItemSKU ).Distinct()
  where ! taggedItems.Contains( i.SKU )
  select i;
```